# Swift expression error (ambiguous without more context)

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift, currently practising some basic stuffs, when I try to figure out why dictionary content is not ordered, I found an answer from someone's post, the solution is add an index before it, like this:

> [Int [String, String]]

when I tried to test it, there's an error about

```
expression type '[Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<String, Int>>]' is ambiguous without more context
```

no idea what went wrong, so I'll just show the code and look for help.

```
var animalNumbers = [[1: ["Cat": 1]], [2: ["Dog": 10]], [3: ["Aye-Aye": 98]]]

for (key, (animal, num)) in animalNumbers {
    print ("\(animal) = \(num)")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you may have misunderstood that suggestion about the numeric key.

First, let's step back. I assume your original dictionary was as follows, and you were trying to solve the issue that the order wasn't preserved:

```
let animals = ["Cat": 1, "Dog": 10, "Aye-Aye": 98]
```

And I suspect you read that other answer and concluded that you needed to convert that to:

```
let animalNumbers = [[1: ["Cat": 1]], [2: ["Dog": 10]], [3: ["Aye-Aye": 98]]]
```

That's an array of nested dictionaries, with each dictionary having a numeric key. But that doesn't make sense. You're solving the problem twice. It's an ordered array of dictionaries, and the numeric key then also provides a mechanism for retrieving the values in some particular order. That's redundant.

The numeric key idea is to make that a dictionary whose key is a numeric value, and whose values are, themselves, dictionaries. If you were to do that, it's simpler than what you have there, but instead merely:

```
let animalNumbers = [0: ["Cat": 1], 1: ["Dog": 10], 2: ["Aye-Aye": 98]]
```

Note, that's a dictionary with numeric key, `[Int: [String: Int]]`. Anyway, once you have that dictionary, you can then theoretically do:

```
for i in 0 ..< animalNumbers.count {
    for (name, value) in animalNumbers[i]! {
        print(name, value)
    }
}
```

But, having reverse engineered what I suspect that other answer was suggesting, I should say that it's really not a very good pattern. If you want to insert values, you have to go through a nightmare of rebuilding all of those numeric keys.

Instead, just use a simple array of dictionaries, `[[String: Int]]`, which is ordered, but eliminates many problems introduced with that manually constructed numeric key:

```
let animals = [["Cat": 1], ["Dog": 10], ["Aye-Aye": 98]]
```

Then you can:

```
for dictionary in animals {
    for (name, value) in dictionary {
        print(name, value)
    }
}
```

---

Finally, even better, you shouldn't be dealing with arrays of dictionaries, but rather an array of custom types:

```
struct Animal {
    let name: String
    let value: Int
}

let animals = [
    Animal(name: "Cat", value: 1),
    Animal(name: "Dog", value: 10),
    Animal(name: "Aye-Aye", value: 98)
]
```

Now that you're dealing with `[Animal]` type, you can just:

```
for animal in animals {
    print(animal.name, animal.value)
}
```

Comment: I think your answer basically cleared my mind, but I have not reached the Structure thing, I will review your questions when I do that. I will post any further question here if I encounter anything about this question, thank you again for the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this-

```
var animalNumbers = [[1: ["Cat": 1]], [2: ["Dog": 10]], [3: ["Aye-Aye": 98]]]

        for animal in animalNumbers {
            for (animalName, num) in animal
            {
                print ("\(animalName) = \(num)")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

- The outer object is an **array** but the code uses **dictionary** enumeration syntax.
- You can't enumerate nested objects in the same `for` loop.

The solution is to use a second for loop

```
let animalNumbers = [[1: ["Cat": 1]], [2: ["Dog": 10]], [3: ["Aye-Aye": 98]]]

for animal in animalNumbers {
   for (key, value) in animal {
        print ("\(key) = \(value)")
    }
}
```

And regarding *why dictionary content is not ordered* that's how a dictionary is defined :

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and values of the same type in a collection **with no defined ordering** .

Comment: I'm not sure about the first issue you mentioned, why did you say the outer object is an **array**, the system detects it as a dictionary object `[Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<String, Int>>]`. I'm a little confused xD

Comment: @zhuqh93 - No, the `[` and `]` around that `Dictionary` expression means that it is an array of dictionaries, i.e. `[Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<String, Int>>]` means `Array<Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<String, Int>>>` (or using the shorthand, it's `[[Int: [String: Int]]]`).